# how to properly pass classNames to a component in react-admin?

Tags: reactjs, jsx, react-admin

I want to pass a value to a component in my react admin to be able to set colors on my Letter Avatar from config.

I am able to pass the values, but for some reason className does not accept it, and remains the color the default color.

my config file:

```
export const SitesData = {
    1: {
        name: "E",
        bgcolor: "secondary",
        bgcolor2: "indigo",
    },
    2: {
        name: "A",
        bgcolor: "primary",
        bgcolor2: "purple",
    },
    3: {
        name: "H",
        bgcolor: "warning",
        bgcolor2: "orange",
    }
};
```

and my code:

```
export const SiteName2 = ({ record = {} }) => {
    const site = SitesData[parseInt(record.site_id)];

    return <MyAvatar source='site_id' sitename={site.name} bgcolor={site.bgcolor2} />;
};
```

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import pure from 'recompose/pure';
import Avatar from '@material-ui/core/Avatar';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import deepOrange from '@material-ui/core/colors/deepOrange';
import deepPurple from '@material-ui/core/colors/deepPurple';
import indigo from '@material-ui/core/colors/indigo';
import green from '@material-ui/core/colors/green';
import classnames from 'classnames';

const styles = {
    orange: {
        margin: 4,
        color: '#fff',
        backgroundColor: deepOrange[500],
    },
    purple: {
        margin: 4,
        color: '#fff',
        backgroundColor: deepPurple[500],
    },
    indigo: {
        margin: 4,
        color: '#fff',
        backgroundColor: indigo[500],
    },
    green: {
        margin: 4,
        color: '#fff',
        backgroundColor: green[500],
    },
};

export const MyAvatar = ({
    className,
    classes = {},
    source,
    sitename,
    bgcolor,
    record = {},
}) => {
    var myClass = `classes.${bgcolor}`;
    console.log("AVATAR: ", myClass, bgcolor);
    return (
                <Avatar className={myClass}>{sitename}</Avatar>
    );
};

MyAvatar.propTypes = {
    className: PropTypes.string,
    classes: PropTypes.object,
    elStyle: PropTypes.object,
    sortBy: PropTypes.string,
    source: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    record: PropTypes.object,
    sitename: PropTypes.string,
    bgcolor: PropTypes.string,
};

// wat? TypeScript looses the displayName if we don't set it explicitly
MyAvatar.displayName = 'MyAvatar';

const MyPureAvatar = withStyles(styles)(pure(MyAvatar));

export default MyPureAvatar;
```

Not sure why myAvatar's classname does not accept the color, but for sure the problem is how I pass the value to it (given I tried to explicit write class.purple for className  for MyAvatar, and it was working.

Comment: Anyone has any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

it turned out that if i pass my value to className like this

```
var myClass = classes[bgcolor];
```

instead of this:

```
var myClass = `classes.${bgcolor}`;
```

classNames accept it, and works as expected